# Strip quantities from list using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have an example shopping list:

```
test_list = "2x 400g beans", "3 x 500 ml choco milk", " 2 chicken breasts"
```

I want to extract the quantities, not including the units, to get the following result:

```
quant_list = ['2x 400', '3 x 500', '2']
```

So far, I have attempted the following:

```
def strip_quantities(string):
    x = re.search("someregex", string)
    sep = x.start() + 1
    return string.rsplit(string[sep])

quant_list = [strip_quantities(x)[0] for x in test_list]
print(quant_list)
```

However, I cannot figure out a regular expression, "someregex", that will allow me to split the string (/) at 400/g, 500/ ml, 2/ chicken.
The regular expression also needs to ignore (not match) the "2x" in the first list item and "3 x" in the second list item.

I think the expression needs to say "match any letter following a digit or any letter following a digit then whitespace, except when that letter is "x". My best guesses for the expression so far are:

```
"\d[^x]|\d\s[^x]"
```

But the output for this is:

```
['2x 4', '2 ', '2 ']
```

Not the intended result as stated above. Any help in finding a solution would be greatly appreciated, using regex or alternative method. I've only been learning Python for a few days so any accompanying explanation would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Try: `r"(?P<quantities>\d+(\s*x\s*\d+)?)"`. `if x: x.group('quantities'): ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```py
\d+(?:\s*x\s*\d+)?
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/mXIJw1/1).

**[Python code](https://tio.run/##PY1BCoMwFET3nmJwY2xFgrYboXiQWkpMowY1kZ8U7OlttNAPs/gzvJnl4wdrym3T82LJg1TklfPPSTuPG@5xseLCeY9WCePiDHGJFVfOMU@Qg5UWs57GPUARDC1HZdCSEs67@BF1lrAXQhv8i6sIwCy8HMIEqdwpQXJglDSvM6urxp3WoPCkdZIdWLoTuvtBBx5uIW08O6y8J/teWJpu2xc)**:

```py
import re
test_list = ["2x 400g beans", "3 x 500 ml choco milk", " 2 chicken breasts"]
for test in test_list:
   match = re.search(r'\d+(?:\s*x\s*\d+)?', test)
   if match:
      print(match.group())
```

**Results**: `2x 400`, `3 x 500`, `2`

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    x                        'x'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
```

Comment: This has worked successfully. Now, I simply need to append the output to a new list. Thank you, this is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex: `((\d([x\s]?)+)+)`

Input: `2x 400g bexfgans", "3 x 500 ml choco milk", " 2 chicken breasts`

Output:

```
2x 400
3 x 500 
2
```

Comment: And you can add others letters or symbols to the whitelist, just add those next to the ```x``` in the regex.

Answer (score 0):

You want "match any set of digits that is not followed by optional whitespace and x`.  For that, you need a "negative lookahead":

```
import re
test_list = "2x 400g beans", "3 x 500 ml choco milk", " 2 chicken breasts"

m = r"(\d+)(?! *x)"
for t in test_list:
    print( re.findall( m, t) )
```

Output:

```
['400']
['500']
['2']
```

Comment: This is semi-useful. However, I think it does not account for the 2x or 3x that I would like to include in the result. I appreciate your help, it has increased my understanding.

Comment: Well, your spec is confusing.  You said "The regular expression also needs to ignore (not match) then "2x" in the first list item" and "3 x" in the second list item".  So, what, EXACTLY, are you expecting the output to be?

Comment: I did state in the spec "I want...to get the following result: quant_list = ['2x 400', '3 x 500', '2']. However, I see how my spec is confusing with the "ignore (not match)" explanation. My apologies, I will try to be clearer next time.